# Visiting Singapore company office short tem to work: which visa?

Tags: visas, singapore, business-travel

I am in the UK and need to work more closely with my boss in Singapore in the SG company office for a period of 3-4 weeks at a time (possibly multiple times over the coming year), but understand that I cannot "work" on a Singapore tourist visa, and have been told there is no short term "EP" employment pass.

I'm not clear on "work" - does that mean being **paid locally**, or receiving **any kind of remuneration** at all?  (*I'm thinking the latter can't be right, as I have known lots of people who have travelled abroad with their companies for 3-4 weeks (including to SG) whilst still being paid in their home country bank account, but do not know what visa they had which facilitated them working.*)

Can someone please clarify if what I intend to do is possible and if so, how?

(I have searched previous answers but cannot find any answering this.)

Comment: Is your company asking you to go to Singapore for work? If so, it's their responsibility to sort out the legality, possibly by engaging an immigration lawyer, although if they are based in Singapore they may have experience of this. As with most countries, you cannot work in Singapore without the correct visa, even if you're being paid by a foreign company. You can look on the Singapore Ministry of Foreign Affairs or Immigration & Checkpoints Authority websites for more information on applying for a visa, but your employer should be the first source of information.

Comment: Please do not take out half your question, you signed for leaving the content up after you posted it and the existing answer is based on the full text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It depends on the nature of your work.** Singapore, somewhat unusually, doesn't have tourist visas, only Short-Term Visit Passes (STVP).  STVPs explicitly allow some work-like activities like "attending meetings" and have a longer list of activities permitted on notification, including "transfer of knowledge on process of new operations in Singapore". See the [Ministry of Manpower](https://www.mom.gov.sg/passes-and-permits/work-pass-exempt-activities/eligible-activities) for a full list.

You can legally conduct these "Work Pass Exempt activities" for up to 90 days in any year-long period, so your plan to visit multiple times is also OK.

Comment: @Wad lambshaanxy's answer is not contradictory to the previous comment. The problem is "...The rest of the time I'd be doing my normal work." STVP works for limited "work like" activities, such as business meetings and "transfer of knowledge. But that's all - what you plan to do (normal, independent, individual, remote work) is not permitted.

Comment: @Wad If they want to do their work according to Singapore law, then yes, they need a Singapore work visa. Many people ignore the rules.